# Where can I find Tara Trishati?

Tags: upasana, tara

As with any devi upasana, there exists a trishati stotram for that devi (eg: Lalita etc.) I tried to find Tara Trishati stotram in various books related to Tara and unable to find it. Can anyone help me in finding Tara Trishati?

Comment: Do you want to know which scripture has Tara Trishati Stotram?

Comment: Are you sure that there even exists one such Stotra?

Comment: @"the destroyer", Yes, I want to know which scripture has it.
@Rickross, yes I am sure because there exists a sahsasranama, ashottara and also a method for upasana.

Comment: I know that there are Sahsranama and Shata nama Stotras for Goddess Tara. But I hv never heard about a Trishati. @ytee

Comment: Thanks @Rickross. What are the places I can search for it. I have searched the dli , archive.org, scribd etc. But are there any other places where I can look for?

Comment: Archive is a very good place. If u can't find it thr thn it's difficult to find it online. Another site is Sanskritdocuments, yet another is Kamakotimandali. @ytee